# Why use setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a class with a bunch of properties, it seems like a hassle to put the properties that I modify inside (for example) this.state.myProp1 instead of this.myProp1. and then I need to make a copy of whatever property it is before I send it off to setState (because I can't mutate it directly). Like an array of objects for example.

At some point I display some of these properties so that means that I need to hold all my class properties inside this state, and then keep track of what I need to refresh, instead of refreshing the whole thing.

I almost prefer to use this.forceUpdate() instead and have my render() refer to class properties directly. Why does react "make" people use this.state and setState. Is it for performance reasons?

Answer (score 2):

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

So basically `setState` is there to tell react when to re-render. Also `setState` behaves asynchronously, and updates the state only when necessary. So if you call `setState` multiple times immediately it will update only on the last one so as to minimize the number of re-renders and be less taxing on the browser. If there was no `setState` and react re-rendered every time the data changed, the browser experience would be terrible.

You don't have to use React `this.state` and `setState` if you don't want to. You can always use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) to manage the state.

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made.

And yeah, that's why you've to *make a copy of whatever property it is before I send it off to setState*

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, component state is an elegant concept for some special case. for example when you want to monitor the content change of a text input on live, that is, not after hit save or submit button. under such situation, a component state would be ideal place to store the temporary input and you will not get overhead to use redux action to respond on the  every incomplete input. it is just like a buffer to provide performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Reasons behind `setState`

The main reason for having to use `setState` is its asynchronous execution, from the react docs:

> React intentionally “waits” until all components call setState() in their event handlers before starting to re-render. This boosts performance by avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

If the state object was updated synchronously it would cause consistency issues, since `props` are not updated until the parent component is re-rendered, so, mutating `this.state` directly would lead to inconsistency between props and state.

For further reference, you can check this [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710) Github thread.

#### 2. Reasons behind `this.state`

The main advantage of the `state` object is its immutability which couldn't be accomplished with component properties, also there is the separation of responsibility between `props` and `state`, which is way easier to handle and update individually.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does react "make" people use this.state and setState. Is it for performance reasons?

That's a good question - the existing answer from J. Pichardo is quite correct but I wanted to address the why in a little more depth - as opposed to what or how.

Really a better question is - why does React exist? According to [this article](https://techlaunch.io/blog/everyone-switch-react/)

> React’s one-way data flow makes things much simpler, more predictable, and less bug-prone. One way data flow greatly simplifies your thinking about state because no view can ever mutate the state directly. Views can only send actions up to the global state store.

Really theres a whole bunch of reasons why React has it's place as a useful UI library.  But in regards to your question - uni-directional data flow - this is the main reason.

relational UIs get complex. When an app has to consume, display and update even just a modest amount of relational data and have that information displayed across multiple elements, things can get messy fast.

Using state and props the way that React does allows one to differentiate and guarantee whether a piece of the UI will just receive data to display or whether it might change it too.

If you store that data just in a random key you have no real way of knowing whether the value is changed and what changed it. By separating out your state from your component in this way, it decouples the data from the element and makes it much easier to share data between elements and also change that data in different ways.

according to [this article](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/c-sharp/understanding-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling) on coupled object interfaces a tightly coupled entity is bad because:

> A tightly Coupled Object is an object that needs to know about other objects and are usually highly dependent on each other's interfaces. When we change one object in a tightly coupled application often it requires changes to a number of other objects. There is no problem in a small application we can easily identify the change. But in the case of a large applications these inter-dependencies are not always known by every consumer or other developers or there is many chance of future changes.

This very much is applicable in UI development also. In my opinion this is why not setting state is going to cause you some pain later on.

Comment: this doesn't address my question at all

Comment: Yes it does. You state "it seems like a hassle to store data using setState" and later on "Why does react "make" people use this.state and setState" and i'm saying React makes you do this because it forces you to separate data from the component itself and it forces you to update elements only from one direction.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer don't get me wrong. But you're describing why it's generally good to decouple data. this is true but it's too general. I asked something very specific about setState.

Comment: But thats one of the primary reasons why state and props exist in React... and why you should use setState. Because when you use setState it allows React to manage state internally and uses its own methods to update the DOM when it is most appropriate as opposed to you arbitrarily setting values and then having to keep track of them yourself. Why use React at all if you dont want to use it's API?

Comment: the classes of the components themselves keep state, just by setting class variables. that's why classes are used as components. I just thought it was redundant to use this.state.* instead of this.*

Comment: @foreyez - if you want to get really technical classes don't exist in JS they are objects that receive prototypal inheritance. Crudely speaking, using this.setState() updates state through the state object that then can perform other code based upon listeners and can update UI if necessary. Assigning straight to the passed component object bypasses the state object and as such is not guaranteed to update correctly and can cause hard-to-find bugs and is why this is officially not supported by the React team.

Comment: Secondly immediately down-voting my answer because you don't understand what i'm referring to isn't the best approach and doesn't really help the SO community, you should have asked for further clarification. Also there are a couple of correct answers here and you should accept one.